# yum update keeps throwing errors

Tags: fedora, yum

I am on a fedora 34 and occasionally have strange behavior when I try to run any yum command. Many times, it will take 30 seconds before the process does anything, but then proceeds normally. Other times, it will simply throw these curl errors:

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'updates':
  - Curl error (23): Failed writing received data to disk/application for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f34&arch=x86_64 [Failure writing output to destination]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (23): Failed writing received data to disk/application for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f34&arch=x86_64 [Failure writing output to destination]
```

Once I get these errors, I have to reboot to fix them.
Anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: you most likely have a broken file system, so you can't write files. Or your disk is full – but rebooting would normally not fix that.

Comment: btw, by now, `yum` really just is `dnf` with a decorative wrapper.

Comment: How do I find the root cause of the corrupted file system?

Comment: usually: not at all, you just backup and try to repair. First verify it's actually a broken file system.